# input and output to fully connected layer

Tags: neural-network

I have an input vector of size 384. It is to be inputted to FC layer with one hidden layer. The output should be a vector of 3.
How is it possible? What is the math behind the calculations in FC layer?

Answer (score 1):

A Fully Connected network looks like this:

[image]

You **input layer** can be of any size, and your **output** layer can be of any size as well.

The **hidden layer** in the middle has a size that *you need to define*.

Each layer is a Fully Connected layer because it has a connection to all nodes in the previous layer. So output nodes have connections to all nodes in the hidden layer. And, all nodes in the hidden layer have access to all nodes in the input layer.